# Django - Reduce URL query-string length

Tags: django, http, django-forms, query-string

I been working with Django Forms for a while but recently I had to create a form to search for data with a MultipleChoiceField.
Since the URL must be shared between the users the form performs a GET to the server to keep the search parameters in the query-string.
The problem is that if multiple options are checked the length of the URL increases too much. For example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/search?source=1&source=2&source=3...
```

Is there anyway working with django forms to get a url like the following:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/search?source=1-2-3...
```

Or is it a better approach to create a token that compress the query-string parameters?

The form is then used to make a search over ElasticSearch. I'm not using djangos models.

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `get` and `get_context_data` on a `TemplateView` could work. Then you could have a URL like this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/search?sources=1,2`

```
class ItemListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sources = self.request.GET.get('sources')
        self.sources = sources.split(',') if sources else None

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.sources:
            context['search-results'] = self.get_search_results(
                self.sources,
            )

        return context

    def get_search_results(self, sources):
        """
        Retrieve items that have `sources`.
        """
        # ElasticSearch code here…

        data = {
            '1': 'Honen',
            '2': 'Oreth',
            '3': 'Vosty',
        }

        return [data[source_id] for source_id in sources]
```

Now, if the `/search?sources=1,2` URL was requested the template context would have `Honen` and `Oreth` in it as the variable `search-results`.

Comment: Hi Matt, I think that's a good idea but doesn't apply to my problem. I forgot to mention that I'm not using a Django model. The data comes from ElasticSearch so there is no traditional model involved. I will update the question.

Comment: In that case, you could use a `TemplateView` and add a method to retrieve the results from ElasticSearch. I'll update my answer.